# Observe file mutations and upload to ftp

Tags: osx, ftp

So I want to have my workspace in a folder. Later I'd probably also want to run Babel and an SCSS compiler there.

Now I want a tool that observes the files in that folder (and it's subfolders) and automatically uploads them to my ftp server. Sadly, I couldn't find anything up till now...

Comment: Welcome :-) I think it will help if add the [tag:backup] tag. All that you seem to be looking for is a free backup/mirror app, and we have ***many*** of those here, which accepts a remote path as a destination. Just rephrase it to "mirror directory to LAN" and you should get answer. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution: http://en.dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realsync/ seems to work just fine for what I wanted...